# MySQL DATE type é mostrado como DATETIME numa datagrid

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, wpf, datetime

Crio uma base de dados muito simples com o comando seguinte:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ABC`.`Socio` (
    `idSocio` INT NOT NULL,
    `SocioNome` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    `SocioDataNasc` DATE NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idSocio`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Os *inserts* utilizados no exemplo são:

```
INSERT INTO `ABC`.`Socio` (`idSocio`, `SocioNome`, `SocioDataNasc`) VALUES (1, 'Trampa', '1946-06-14');
INSERT INTO `ABC`.`Socio` (`idSocio`, `SocioNome`, `SocioDataNasc`) VALUES (2, 'Bill', '1955-10-28');
INSERT INTO `ABC`.`Socio` (`idSocio`, `SocioNome`, `SocioDataNasc`) VALUES (3, 'Cristiano', '1985-02-05');
INSERT INTO `ABC`.`Socio` (`idSocio`, `SocioNome`, `SocioDataNasc`) VALUES (4, 'Francisco', '1936-12-17');
INSERT INTO `ABC`.`Socio` (`idSocio`, `SocioNome`, `SocioDataNasc`) VALUES (5, 'Obama', '1961-08-04');
```

A parte relativa ao XAML que vai buscar os dados para a datagrid é:

```
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="dataGridProdutos" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=carregarDados}" CanUserResizeRows="True" AlternatingRowBackground="GhostWhite"  AlternationCount="2" CanUserAddRows="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=idSocio}" Header="Número de Sócio" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=SocioNome}" Header="Nome" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=SocioDataNasc}" Header="Data de Nascimento" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Porque razão obtenho a data num formato que aparenta ser do tipo DATETIME?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É assim mesmo. Em C# não existe o tipo `Date`, apenas `DateTime` ou `TimeSpan`, sendo assim é adicionado a parte de hora na sua data.  Você pode resolver com um `StringFormat`.

```
StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy
```

Ficando assim:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=SocioDataNasc, StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy}" Header="Data de Nascimento" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a formatação `{Binding Path=SocioDataNasc, StringFormat = d}`:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="dataGridProdutos" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=carregarDados}" CanUserResizeRows="True" AlternatingRowBackground="GhostWhite"  AlternationCount="2" CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=idSocio}" Header="Número de Sócio" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=SocioNome}" Header="Nome" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=SocioDataNasc, StringFormat = d}" Header="Data de Nascimento" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WPF/Binding.cs).

Veja a [documentação dos formatos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) se desejar personalizar mais.